# Slow ajax return Active Directory users

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

Part of the script I am writing involves a Google style intelligent search. The page header contains the following Javascript:

```
function showCustomer(str)
{
// remove white space from the name entered on the search screen
str = str.replace(" ", "");
var xmlhttp;    
if (str=="")
{
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="No records found";
  return;
 }
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5



 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","get_customer.asp?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The element txthint is an empty div and, on the textbox element, I have an onkeyup. This worked well when we were using a Microsoft Access database but now, when I am using Active Directory, it seems to take a while - first bringing back the whole list and then filtering the results. The code in this file looks like:

```
         <%@LANGUAGE="VBScript"%>
    <!-- #include file="pagelets/includes/results.asp"-->
    <%
    response.Buffer = True
    response.expires=-1
    dim name, ADUser, objCom, objCon, objRS, membership, CentralUser, GroupMember
    name = request.querystring("q")
    ADUser = "LDAP://OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=internal"
    ' ADUser holds the LDAP query string
    Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
    objCon.Properties("User ID") = "EXAMPLE\testuser"
    objCon.Properties("Password") = "password"
    objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
    objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"
    ' objCon is the Active Directory object 
    Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon
   ' This sets the objCom to use the objCon object. The following query can then run and pull information back
    objCom.CommandText = "SELECT givenName, sn, mail, telephonenumber, mobile, description, sAMAccountName, cn, UserAccountControl, memberOf FROM '" & ADUser & "' where givenName='*" & name & "*' OR sn='*" & name & "*' OR description='*" & name & "*' OR cn='*" & name & "*'AND UserAccountControl <> 514 ORDER BY cn ASC" 
    'This query selects information from Active Directory where the firstname, lastname or description is similar to the string which the user typed in. 512 is the User Account Control value for a normal account and 2 is the UserAccountControl value for a disabled account so we add these together to get 514. This is a normal user account that has been disabled. 
Set objRS = objCom.Execute
'This will execute the above object
Response.Write "<table>" + vbCrLf
Do While Not objRS.EOF Or objRS.BOF
'This loops through the resultsset
Response.Write "    <tr>"
Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("givenName") + "</td>"
Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("sn") + "</td>"
Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("mail") + "</td>"
    ' Check if field is null to avoid error
    If IsNull(objRS.Fields("Description").Value) Then
            sDesc = ""
else
For Each item In objRS.Fields("description").Value
                    sDesc = item + "<br>"
            Next
end if
Response.Write "<td>" + sDesc + "</td>"
Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("mobile") + "</td>"
CentralUser = mid(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER"), 11)
'This takes what the user is logged in as and, since, it will have the domain name in front of it, it will strip the RUGBY_B_C\ off 
GroupMember = GroupCheck(CentralUser)
'This passes CentralUser to the GroupCheck function
Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("telephonenumber") + "</td>"
if objRS("sAMAccountName") = CentralUser then
'If the account name held in AD is different to the one the user is logged in with, a blank cell is output. If they are the same, a link allowing the user to edit their entry is displayed


    Response.Write "<td><a href='entry.asp?account_name=" + objRS("sAMAccountName") + "'>Edit</a></td>"
    'This will make a link using the sAMAccountName

elseif GroupMember = 1 then
'These are the accounts that are members of the "Team Carol" group

Response.Write "<td><a href='entry.asp?account_name=" + objRS("sAMAccountName") + "'>Edit</a></td>"

    'This will make a link using the sAMAccountName
    else

    Response.Write "<td></td>"
    'If neither condition is true, a blank cell is output
    end if

    Response.Write "</tr>" + vbCrL
    objRS.MoveNext
Response.Flush
    Loop
    Response.Write "</table>"
    ' Clean up
    objRS.Close
    objCon.Close
    Set objRS = Nothing
    Set objCon = Nothing
    Set objCom = Nothing
    %>
```

I have absolutely no iddea why it works instantly when pulling from a database but, when it pulls from AD, it takes time

Comment: Part of it could be that AD is just inherently slower than a "real" database. But most of this went whooshing somewhere above my head, so what do I know. :)

Comment: I can't help feeling that it must be to do with AD but, when I go to get_customer.asp directly manually setting the GET variable, it brings back the results quickly so it must be AJAX but it is the same code I used before